# Print Unicode escape codes from variable

Tags: ruby, unicode-escapes

I have a list of Unicode character codes that I would like to output with `rumoji`. Here's the code I'm using to iterate over my data.

```
require "rumoji"

# this works
puts Rumoji.decode("\u{1F600}")

# feed some data
data = [
    "1F600",
    "1F476",
    "1F474"
]

data.each do |line|
    # this doesn't work
    puts Rumoji.decode("\u{#{line}}")
    puts Rumoji.decode("\u{" + line + "}")
end
```

I'm not sure how I can use variable names inside the escaped string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can not use `\u` along with string interpolation, since `\u` takes precedence. What one might do, is to [`Array#pack`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-pack) an array of integers:

```
▶ data.map { |e| e.to_i(16) }.pack 'U*'
#⇒ ""
```

Comment: I tried figuring out how to use to output each line, not the full array. I would rather be able to concat strings to my output. This doesn't work `puts e.to_i(16).pack("U*")`. Any hints?

Comment: Since `pack` is defined on `Array`: `["1F600".to_i(16)].pack 'U'`.

Comment: Thank you so much!